# Repeat String Recursively

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, repeat

This is homework. I get the logic but i got stuck on the code. I've done it with normally way and it takes 1 week to get the code. I need to get repeat string with recursive way in Java.
This is my code :

```
static String repeatString (final int n, final String[] syllables, final String currentWord) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(currentWord);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++) {
            repeatString(n - 1, syllables, currentWord + syllables[i]);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

if i call in main method like

```
String[] str = {"a", "b"};
    repeatString(1, str, " ");
```

then i get output (a,b) if i change to

```
repeatString(2,str," ");
```

then i get output ( aa,ab,ba,bb) if i change to

```
repeatString(3,str," ");
```

then i get output (aaa,aab,aba,abb,baa,bab,bba,bbb) and so on.
So basically it is like 2 to the power to n. If n=1, i got 2, if n=3, i got 8, and so on.
I would be grateful if someone can help me to get this code in recursive way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you will never learn if you ask someone write code for you

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is the output wrong?  What do you need help with?  (And please give a _specific_ answer; "I need to get this code in recursive way" is not specific at all).

Comment: not write the code. but the logic to do this in recursive way. because there is no for loop, while, etc.

Comment: The question is to make repeat string from 2 or more with f(n) = string[] ^ n in recursive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have there is recursive already. Being recursive does NOT mean it should have no for loops. A recursive method in cheap words means the method calls itself, which yours does.

Comment: so my code is right. But i learn recursive in Coursera ( sort of online study ), there is no (for-loop,while). There was just if and return.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. There is nothing wrong with combining a loop with recursion. Is your end result (i.e. what gets printed) what you want